# Summation of Combinations Shortcut Formula?

Tags: combinatorics

For $^nC_k$, where $n = 15$ and $k = 1 \to 15$, is there a formula that finds this total without using summation?

A shorter example that uses summation:

$$\begin{align}
^{15}C_1 &= 15 \\
^{15}C_2 &= 105 \\
\implies {^{15}C_1} + {^{15}C_2} &= 120
\end{align}$$

I feel like there should be a modification (e.g. $n+1$ or something) that allows the summation to be found without adding up all the separate solutions for $k = 1 \to 15$.

Thanks!

Comment: Try looking at the binomial theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: I can't figure out how that applies...

Comment: Okay, I got it.  Power(2,15)-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frpzzd said, you can look at the binomial theorem and related topics.

The relevant formula you're looking for is:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$

Since you're only summing from $1$ to $n$ your result would be $2^n -1$

Source for further reading: https://brilliant.org/wiki/binomial-theorem-n-choose-k/#pascals-triangle